# ¿Cómo activar el botón?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo el siguiente login, en el cuál pido usuario y contraseña, valido los datos en la base de datos, lo que pretendo realizar es que cuando el usuario sea correcto se active otro boton que se encuentra en el mismo formulario.

```
           <form action="" method="post">
           <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Usuario">
           <input type="password" name="contra" placeholder="Contraseña">
           <input type="submit" value="INGRESAR">
           </form>
```

El login lo valido de la siguiente manera

```
           <?php
            require_once "Conexion/Conexion.php";
          $alert = '';
           session_start();
          if(!empty($_SESSION['active']))
          {
            header('location: Sistema/inicio.php');
          }else{
          if(!empty($_POST))
          {
          if (empty($_POST['nombre']) || empty($_POST['contra'])) 
          {
          $alert = 'Ingrese su usuario y contraseña por favor';
           }else {
          require_once "Conexion/Conexion.php";
          $usuario = ($_POST['nombre']);
           $pass = ($_POST['contra']);
          $query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = '$usuario' AND 
          contra = '$pass'");
         $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
         if ($result > 0) {
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $_SESSION['active'] = true;
        $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $data['id_usuario'];
        $_SESSION['nombre'] = $data['nombre'];
        $_SESSION['contra'] = $data['contra'];
        $_SESSION['rol'] = $data['rol'];
       header('location: Sistema/inicio.php');
       }else{
       $alert ='Datos incorrectos';
        session_destroy();
       }   
       }
       }
       }
       ?>
```

La validación si me la hace, pero ahora necesito que al momento de validar se active el siguiente boton

```
         <input type="submit" value="INICIAR">
```

Comment: Con puro PHP?...

Comment: Si se puede porqué todo lo valido dentro del mismo formulario

Comment: Tienes dos opciones: 1. Recargar el formulario notificando que el login fue correcto y mostrando el botón que deseas y 2. Pasar los datos via ajax y ante una respuesta de aceptación mostrar el botón como parte de una *reacción*. La primera es "equivalente" a redirigir. En caso de que el formulario de login pudiera ser invocado desde cualquier página a la que se niegue acceso por no estar loggeado aparece otra opción redirigir a la página que estaba prohibida por haberse "levantado" el bloqueo. Usa estas ideas para reformular la pregunta.

Comment: En caso de que elijas la primera opción piensa tu página como un juego con dos secciones: una para aceptar la entrada del login y otra para seguir adelante. Las separas con un if. La primera se muestra sólo si no hay post, el post trae la info de login y el login es incorrecto y la segunda se muestra sólo si hay post de login y fue correcto. Si la segunda gestiona entradas o botones adicionales da paso a lo específico de su post.

Comment: @quevedo amigo crees que me puedas apoyar por chat?

Comment: si. Pero, hoy ando un poco enredado. suelo estar hacia las 20:00 (GMT -5) en el chat en español. A otras horas es muy probable que veas mi avatar ahí, pero muy seguramente esté ocupado y pase intempestivamente por momentos. Te espero mañana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo bien el propósito de lo que quieres hacer por que tu botón **submit** tiene que estar activo para poder enviar tu formulario, en todo caso si quieres agregar otro boton despues del logeo bastaria que antes de terminar tu form agregues

```
if($_SESSION['active'] = true){ echo '<input type="button" value="INICIAR">';}
```